# How to add pipelines support to a Jenkins plugin?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I've wrote a Jenkins plugin some time ago and as starting with Jenkins 2.0 they've added pipelines support I'm looking into updating the plugin to have support to be used from the pipelines.

Any idea what needs to be done to make the plugin support being called from a Jenkins pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the well documented [Developer Guide](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/DEVGUIDE.md) that will guide you through the process of making your plugin pipeline compatible !